# what happen if fail to delete a shared memory segment

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, shared-memory

According to my observation, if I terminate my process without removing the shared memory segment, that shared memory segment will just stay there, in `/dev/shm/xxxx`, even no other processes are using it.  **Does it mean a memory leak ?**(and after I restart my machine it will disappear) Why doesn't linux provide a mechanism to maintain a reference count on shared memory and then the system can delete it when no process is using it.

Since process might crash, or I just failed to catch some exceptions....anyway there is a large chance that I fail to remove that shared memory segment when process terminated abnormally.

My use case: I'm running several working processes who share the same memory segment for communication. And there is no master node to coordinate things. The strategy is the last exit node will close the shared memory segment.

By the way I'm using `boost::interprocess` instead of sytem level `shm_open` but I think their behavior should be the same.

Comment: How do you know which is the last exit node?

Comment: Typically, what you want to know is which node is the first to start. That node should clean up any messes that were left behind, and then create a new shared memory segment.

Comment: You can get the behavior you describe: After creating and mapping a shared memory object, use `shm_unlink` to disassociate it from the name. It will continue existing until the last reference is closed, such as when the last process with it mapped unmaps it.

Comment: @user3386109 maybe through a file lock or something.... since I can know how much processes are opening a file and even when a process crash the reference count on that file will decrease.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Posix standard requires that (emphasis added):

> When a shared memory object is created, the state of the shared memory object, including all data associated with the shared memory object, **persists until the shared memory object is unlinked** and all other references are gone. It is unspecified whether the name and shared memory object state remain valid after a system reboot.

In other words, shared memory objects are basically like temporary files; they are intended to be persistent, at least for the duration of a session. All the processes using a particular named shared memory object could crash, and you could still fire up a new process and recover the contents of the shared memory object.

Since Linux attempts to be consistent with the Posix standard, it implements shared memory objects in the same way, which means that they hang around (until a reboot) unless cleaned up manually.

A shared memory object which is no longer in use by any active process is not exactly a memory leak, since it will rapidly get swapped out if there is memory pressure (and swapping is enabled). However, it's a good idea to periodically clean up your shared memory objects yourself. There are a variety of strategies for doing so, depending on the precise nature of your application.

A simple (but by no means universal) solution is to unlink the shared memory object as soon as you know that no new processes will need to open it. Unlinking the object effectively removes its name so that it is no longer possible to `shm_open` it, but the unlinked object persists as long as some process has an open reference to it. (The OS does keep a reference count; however, the name counts as a reference so as long as the name exists, the object does, too.) This same strategy is also often used by applications which create temporary files.